# How to use xml pass the data to javascript by DHTMLX

Tags: javascript, php, xml, dhtmlx

I use DHTMLX. I want to use the ajax component get the data from php, the php will create the xml. How to get this xml data into javascript.

```
enter code here 
           dhtmlxAjax.get("php/getUsername.php", function(r){
           r = r.xmlDoc.responseXML; // will give you DOM object
                //console.log(r.firstChild.tagName);
                alert(r.firstChild.tagName("param1"));
        });
```

thank you

Comment: looks like you are already getting your xml data and are accessing it. Note though that `tagName` is not a function

Comment: which XML data?, you've shown javascript, and what looks like an (invalid) attempt to alert something called param1

Comment: How to use alert() function to show the data. thank you.

Comment: But I use alert(r.firstChild.tagName); can not show the data.

Comment: the xml is <param0>
<param1>test</param1>
</param0>  It just show the tagname "param0", I want to show the data is test, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the php echo function to echo the php variable into a java script variable.

eg. If you have a php variable called $XMLData you would do the following

```
var XMLdata = <?php echo $XMLData; ?>
```

Then on page load your php variable becomes a javascript variable and can be used. from anywhere in javascript provided that the variable is within its scope.